# OpenProcess Failure (SeDebugPrivilege?)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, openprocess

I'm trying to use OpenProcess, for some reason it keeps failing.

```
HANDLE GetProcessPid()
{
    DWORD pid = 0;
    wchar_t ProcessName[] = L"notepad.exe";

    // Create toolhelp snapshot.
    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    PROCESSENTRY32 process;
    ZeroMemory(&process, sizeof(process));
    process.dwSize = sizeof(process);

    // Walkthrough all processes.
    if (Process32First(snapshot, &process))
    {
        do
        {
            if (wcscmp(process.szExeFile, ProcessName) == 0)
            {
                pid = process.th32ProcessID;
                break;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(snapshot, &process));
    }

    CloseHandle(snapshot);

    if (pid != 0)
    {
        return OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

This always returns 0xcccccccccccccccc or 0x0000000000000020 even when I've set the pid manually when calling OpenProcess.

I've tried running as admin outside of debugging inside visual studio and get the same results, after searching, I think I need to enable debug priviledges (SeDebugPrivilege), how do I do this in visual studio 2013?

Comment: One of the first two links on Google for "SeDebugPrivilege" was C code on MSDN for enabling this privilege.

Comment: Now the process handle is 0x00000000000000b4 , help, process.th32ProcessID is the correct pid (6508 for me).

Comment: According to the documentation, the only erroneous return value of `OpenProcess` is `NULL`, so all three of those results are valid if that's true.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, you just need to run your executable as administrator and it works, I just tested it.